# angular and ng-options and json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a json like :

```
{
   "0":{"login":"user1","licenses":{"x":4},"open":true},
   "1":{"login":"user2","licenses":{"x":6,"xx":9,"xxx":7},"open":true}
}
```

And this

```
<select ng-model="userToAdd" ng-options="user.login as user.login for user in listUsers"></select>
```

Doesn't work, but I don't know why.

Here's the relevant controller code:

```
$scope.getUsers = function() {
    $scope.listUsers = {};
    var indexLogin = 0;
    var indexLicense = 0;
    $http.get('listUser').success(function(data) {
        _.each(data, function(licenses, userLogin){
            $scope.listUsers[indexLogin] = {};
            $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].login = userLogin;
            $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].licenses = {};
            _.each(licenses, function(license){
                if(license.feature.name in $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].licenses){
                    $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].licenses[license.feature.name] = $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].licenses[license.feature.name] + 1;
                } else {
                    $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].licenses[license.feature.name] = 1;
                }
                indexLicense++;
            })
                $scope.listUsers[indexLogin].open = false;
            indexLogin++;
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: Please show your ng-controller code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `listUsers` is an object, not an array. So the ng-options should be changed accordingly:

```
ng-options="user.login as user.login for (_, user) in listUsers"
```

Alternatively, you might want to change `listUsers` format so it becomes a proper array. Instead of using incrementing `indexLogin`, just <del>create a new object at each step, then push this object into `listUsers` array</del> use `_.map` to prepare a proper array of objects:

```
$scope.listUsers = [];
$http.get('listUser').success(function(data) {
    $scope.listUsers = _.map(data, function(licenses, userLogin){
        var user = {
           login: userLogin,
           open: false,
           licences: {}
        };
        _.each(licenses, function(license){
            var featureName = license.feature.name;
            user.licences[featureName] = (user.licences[featureName] || 0) + 1;
        });
        return user;
    })
});
```